update html page on POST request in go
i am writing a go server that receives GET and POST request, on GET requests, i am able to serve a html page and on POST request i receive a JSON, now i want to update the html page when i receive the POST request.
So far i been able to update the html page when i refresh the entire page.
With this i am able to show/update the receive data when i refresh the whole page
this is the go file section that deals with the request and serves the html page
func (h *handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    b, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    
    event := r.URL.Query().Get("event")
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        
        switch event {
        case "up":
            err = h.up(b)
        case "join":
            err = h.join(b)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("handler para el evento %s no esta implementado \n", event)
            return
        }
    } else if r.Method == "GET" {
        
        switch r.URL.String() {
        case "/":
            //cargar aqui la pagina web
            tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html"))
            tmpl.Execute(w, data)
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("metodo request '%s' retorna error: %s\n", event, err)
    }
}

This is the HTML file that gets serve
layout.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Jorge Felipe González Orellana"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            *{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body {
                background-color: #7A82AB;
                color: floralwhite;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
            }

            
            .nav-grnl {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                background-color: #333333;
                height: 7vh;
            }

            .nav-grnl a {
                margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                display: flex;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: floralwhite;
                border-radius: 12px;
            }

            .nav-grnl a:hover {
                color: black;
                background-color: floralwhite;
            }

            .logo {
                display: flex;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                height: inherit;
                width: 7vh;
            }

            
            .contenedor-gnrl {
                display: grid;
                position: fixed;
                grid-template-areas: 
                    'left right';
                width: 100vw;
                height: 88vh;
            }

            
            .main-section {
                background-color: floralwhite;
                color: black;
                grid-area: left;
                width: 80vw;
            }

            
            .main-info {
                /* background-color: #7A82AB; */
                background-color: #999792;
                color: black;
                grid-area: right;
                width: 20vw;
            }

            
            .footer-gnrl {
                background-color: #333333;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 5vh;
            }

            p {
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                .grid-container  {
                    grid-template-areas: 
                    'header header' 
                    'left left' 
                    'right right' 
                    'footer footer';
                }
            }

        </style>
        <title>2veinte test</title> 

        
        <script>
            setInterval(ObtDispos, 1000);
            function ObtDispos(){
                var dispos = "{{ .Dispositivos }}"
                console.log(dispos)
            }
        </script>      
    </head>
    <body>       
        
        <div class="nav-grnl">
            <svg class="logo"></svg>
            <a href="/">Link</a>
            <a href="/">Link</a>
            <a href="/">Link</a>
        </div>

        
        <div class="contenedor-gnrl">
            <!-- izq -->
            <div class="main-section">
                <!-- base para mostrar data -->
                <div class="DispositivosLoraWAN" id="DispositivosLoraWAN">
                    {{range .Dispositivos}}
                        <div>
                            <h6>{{.Nombre_Disp}}</h6>
                            <h6>{{.DevEUI}}</h6>
                            <h6>{{.Data}}</h6>
                        </div>
                    {{end}}
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div class="main-info">
                <p>info principal</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div class="footer-gnrl">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

The CSS and JS part are inside the <head></head> tag.
I'm relatively new to Go, so I don't have much knowledge of all the packages out there.

If you want to update a page based on response received from the server after you perform an Ajax call, you have to do it using Javascript on the client side. This has nothing to do with your server side Go code.

what i want its to send data from the server to the page when the data its reveived on the server.
